# python wget library not returning if internet goes down for some times. How can I return with error if Internet is down?

Tags: python, wget

I have below code to download a file inside a loop,

```
import wget
try:
    wget.download(url)
except:
    pass
```

But if the Internet goes down, it doesn't return!
So my whole loop is stuck.

I want to repeat the same download if internet goes down. So I wanna know does any error happen.

How can i mitigate this?

Comment: Have you looked at the `signal` module?

Comment: ping something then act on the result

Comment: Unrelated but: remove the `except: pass` part. It's worse than useless, it's harmful (and shouldn't even be legal).

Comment: `wget` does not pass any timeout to the underlying urllib calls and does not allow to pass any, so your best best is probably to switch to `requests` instead.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to move your download code to a thread and make it a separate process which can be interrupted.

You can use python Thread and Timer module to achieve it.

```
from threading import Thread, Timer
from functools import partial
import time
import urllib

def check_connectivity(t):
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen("http://google.com", timeout=2)
    except Exception as e:
        t._Thread__stop()

class Download(Thread):


  def run(self):
    print("Trying to download file....")
    con = partial(check_connectivity, self)
    while True:
      t = Timer(5, con) # Checks the connectivity every 5 second or less.
      t.start()
      # your download code....




def main():
  down = Download()
  down.start()
  down.join()
```

You code move your main download loop inside the thread's run method. And start a timer inside which listens for the network connectivity.

Comment: @m.j perhaps you can accept this answer if it works ?